# Why browser render image color is different from Preview?

Tags: image, firefox, browser, colors, preview

[image]

The browser is [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), as compare to [Preview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(Mac_OS)), it shows a difference in color.

**(Same image showing in different viewer)**

Anyone know why is this happen? How can I solve this?